# Get dataframe values by down instead of across?

Tags: python, pandas

```
          0         2
0 -0.089329 -0.945867
1 -0.932132  0.017587
2 -0.016692  0.254161
3 -1.143704  1.193555
4 -0.077118 -0.862495
```

`df.values` gives

```
[[-0.089329, -0.945867], [-0.932132, 0.017587], ...]
```

But I want:

```
[[-0.089329, -0.932132, ...], [-0.945867, 0.0.017587, ...]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need transpose numpy array or pandas DataFrame:

```
df.values.T
```

Or:

```
df.T.values
```